# SQL Server to MySQL function using apostrophes, inverted commas and commas in values

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have problem that i cant solve. The select that im doing returns 8500+ values many of them contain apostrophe, inverted commas, comas (")(')(,). 
I'm using sql to mysql connection.

So its not one value that i need to deal with. I know how to deal with one value useing ‘Eat at Joe’’s -- It’’s Good Food!’ or ‘Eat at Joe\’s -- It\’s Good Food!’;. 
 Can someone help me please

```
DECLARE @dogno varchar(5)
DECLARE @ime VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @adresa VARCHAR(200)

DECLARE nam CURSOR FOR
    select Klienti.naziv as ime, Ulici.naziv+' '+Klienti.ulica_br as adresa , tKlienti_Dogovori.dogovor_br as dogno 
    from Klienti_Dogovori
    INNER JOIN Klienti on Klienti.id=Klienti_Dogovori.klient_id
    INNER JOIN Ulici on Ulici.id=Klienti.ulica_id
    where Klienti_Dogovori.usluga_id=2 and Klienti_Dogovori.aktiven=1
open nam
    fetch next from nam into @ime, @adresa, @dogno
    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    DECLARE @sync varchar(max)
            set @sync = '''update users set name=''' +cast(@ime as VARCHAR(200))+ ''', address=''' +cast (@adresa as varchar(200))+ ''' where dognumber=''' + cast (@dogno as varchar(5))
        Execute(@sync) at mysqlserver
    fetch next from nam into @ime, @adresa, @dogno
    END
close nam
deallocate nam
```

This function works fine until it comes to a value that has apostrophe, inverted commas or comas (")(')(,).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i found out how to do it ill answer my question. 
Its all in the select

```
select replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(REPLACE(Klienti.naziv,'''',''),'"',''),',',''),'“',''),'„',''),'’',''),'‘','') as ime, replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(Ulici.naziv+' '+Klienti.ulica_br,'''',''),'"',''),',',''),'“',''),'„',''),'’',''),'‘','') as adresa,  Klienti_Dogovori.dogovor_br as dogno
    from Klienti_Dogovori
    INNER JOIN Klienti on Klienti.id=Klienti_Dogovori.klient_id
    INNER JOIN Ulici on Ulici.id=Klienti.ulica_id
    where Klienti_Dogovori.usluga_id=2 and Klienti_Dogovori.aktiven=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Ugh.  You'd be much better executing a stored procedure or UPDATE statement against your linked server than doing this abominable thing!

You should also look at doing a set based update rather than the cursor which is unnecessary and slow.